# write the result for "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol[@jstcache = '8852']")" into a csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to scrape best flights from one website. The result is as shown below.. schedules of 3 best flight flights. Could someone help to write it into a csv under columns: Flightname Time Duration Fare
10:15 PM – 11:50 PM
Scoot
4h 5m
SIN–MAA
Nonstop
$220
round trip
5:40 AM – 7:35 AM
IndiGo
4h 25m
SIN–MAA
Nonstop
$245
round trip
12:10 AM – 1:50 AM
Air-India Express
4h 10m
SIN–MAA
Nonstop
$299
round trip

My code is as below:
flights = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol[@jstcache = '8852']")
print(flights.text)

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv module to write the extracted data.

Example usage reading from csv:

```
import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print(', '.join(row))
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Example usage writing to a csv:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

In your case you can use it like this:

```
import csv
data = ['3:00 PM – 4:25 PM\nThai AirAsia\n2h 25m\nSIN–DMK\nNonstop\n$136\nround trip\n10:05 PM – 11:30 PM\nScoot\n2h 25m\nSIN–DMK\nNonstop\n$137\nround trip\n7:10 PM – 8:40 PM\nJetstar\n2h 30m\nSIN–BKK\nNonstop\n$149\nround trip'][0].split('\n')
numberOfFlights = 3

for i in range(numberOfFlights+1):
    data.insert(7*i+i, '\n')

with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Time' , 'Flightname' , 'Duration' , 'Fare' , 'Trip'])
    spamwriter.writerow(data)
```

Comment: ['3:00 PM – 4:25 PM\nThai AirAsia\n2h 25m\nSIN–DMK\nNonstop\n$136\nround trip\n10:05 PM – 11:30 PM\nScoot\n2h 25m\nSIN–DMK\nNonstop\n$137\nround trip\n7:10 PM – 8:40 PM\nJetstar\n2h 30m\nSIN–BKK\nNonstop\n$149\nround trip']

Comment: from the above output, there are 3 flight deals scraped. I want to write to csv as: